# Aligning gaps in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In the snippet below whichever value is used for `justify-content` we cannot seem to horizontally align the elements around their gaps.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body, div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
div {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  padding: 2rem 0rem;
  background-color: rgba( 0,0,0,0.0725 );
}
span {
  outline: solid 0.1rem red;
}
span:nth-of-type( 2n ) {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>first item</span> <span></span>
  <span>second item</span> <span></span>
  <span>third item(etc)</span> <span></span>
</div>
```

**The below snippet is the desired result.**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body, div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
div {
  width: 10rem; height: 10rem;
  padding: 2rem 0rem;
  background-color: rgba( 0,0,0,0.0725 );
}
span {
  outline: solid 0.1rem red;
}
span:nth-of-type( 2n ) {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 1rem;
}
/* added code below. Using transforms to target each element individually */
span:nth-of-type( 3 ), span:nth-of-type( 4 ) {
  transform: translateX( 0.5rem );
}
span:nth-of-type( 1 ), span:nth-of-type( 2 ) {
  transform: translateX( 1rem );
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>first item</span> <span></span>
  <span>second item</span> <span></span>
  <span>third item(etc)</span> <span></span>
</div>
```

Is there a way to achieve this result above without having to specifically target each element? In a list of 20+ items targeting each element for alignment would be impractical.

***Is the desired result possible without editing the base HTML or targeting each specific element?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To align them to the right as your desired result appears to be, you can just change how you justify the div. Then play with the margins to get it in the right position.

```
div{
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

This will have everything pretty much aligned right and if the empty spans are the same width then the columns will always line up.

Comment: In your question, one of your requirements (both in the code and in the image) was for the items to be horizontally centered. That's why I went with Grid. If horizontal centering was not a requirement then, obviously, this is the simplest and best solution.

Comment: One of the main features of flexbox is aligning elements horizontally or vertically so flexbox was perfect regardless I feel

Answer (score 1):

With flexbox you're working with free space on the line.

This makes it hard to align columns or gaps across rows, because the content in each row may be different, resulting in different lengths, meaning there will be more or less free space.

However, the layout is relatively simple with CSS Grid.

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 2rem;
  grid-auto-rows: 1rem;
  grid-gap: 0.5rem;            /* shorthand for grid-column-gap and grid-row-gap */
  justify-content: center;     /* center the columns */
}

span:nth-child(2n + 1) {
  justify-self: end;
}

span {
  outline: solid 0.1rem red;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  padding: 2rem 0rem;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>first item</span>
  <span></span>
  <span>second item</span>
  <span></span>
  <span>third item(etc)</span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: so then, there is no way to do this with flexbox that meets the questions requirements? Grid is the only option?

Comment: There are no column tracks in flexbox. You're aligning with free space, which varies across rows. So aligning the gaps is not simple. The layout can be achieved, but it would require more HTML are targeted CSS, both of which fall outside the scope of your requirements.